# WordPress Pages - Adding subdirectory to permalink for specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Currently, I have my permalink structure set up such as https://example.com/blog/%postname%/ which makes it so that whenever a blog post is loaded, the URL shows /blog/. I would also like to add the subdirectory /try/ for specific pages. I have tried to use a plugin to add categories to pages so I can create a category and add it that way, but it seems that this is not possible because the "Custom Structure" is already set as noted above.

Does anyone know of a way to add a subdirectory /try/ to specific pages for a WordPress website so the URL for certain pages would be such as https://example.com/try/page-title

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to add rewrite_rule

```
 add_rewrite_rule(
  '^try/([^/]+)/?',
  'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
  'top'
  );
```

Then we need to use the post_link filter to change the link format for certain posts

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_post_permalink', 10, 4 );
function custom_post_permalink( $link, $post = 0 ) {

        $post_cur_id = $post->ID;
        $post_cur_slug = $post->post_name;

        //array of post_ids with try in permalink
        $try_array = array(1,7,22,78);
        
        if(in_array($post_cur_id, $try_array)) {

        
        $slug = '/try/' . $post_cur_slug . '/';
        
        
        $link = home_url($slug, 'https');

        }

        return  $link;

}
```

The array $try_array should contain post_id's in which we change the link format

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand how your code is structured, except for when you add 'custom_post_permalink', 10, 4 ); ? What are the numbers supposed to represent.

Comment: 10 its priority, this is default value and 4 its the number of arguments the function accepts, default is 1, we have more then 1 argument so increase this value

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, if I remove my custom permalink structure /blog/%postname%/ then it works, but only for posts (as in blog posts), but it does not work for pages even though when using inspect element the post id matches the code in the try array. Might you know how to make it work where I can keep the post permalink structure so that when a blog post is loaded it says /blog/blog-title, but also allow it to work for select pages too such as /try/page-title?

Comment: Yes, its code for posts, for pages you need another filter. You have only posts and pages, no custom post types ?

Comment: Yor clear permalink cache after adding this code to functions.php ? At my demo its work with /blog/%postname%/  structure for posts , try now change to /blog/%postname%/  and check.

Comment: When I inspect element, I get a post_id, so I assumed this would be in respect to post_id in the above code on this page that you provided earlier. Would it be logical to replace "post" with "page" and try that? And yes, I did clear the permalink cache.

Comment: If you want it to work for pages you don't need any code, delete what you added, turn on/off the permalinks and then just create a try page and then make all the pages you want child this one. And you'll have links in the format you want.